# How to make Grep non-greedy

Tags: grep

I got a file so something like:

```
helsoidfiejoih
heye heye hey 
me is hi
```

The file can have any number of lines or characters in it the point is that it is a text file of some sort. Now the I need to use grep to do some operation so that the first parameter passed to grep is the filename and the second parameter is the pattern. But grep does a greedy match so it matches the whole line instead of a non greedy match which is what I want(non-greedy match). Now I tried:

```
grep -Ec -Po "$2" $1
```

It gives me conflicting expressions. And the user can enter any pattern A.K.A RE so the -E is a necessary option. Is there a way to make the grep non-greedy? I was told that the -P option makes the grep command non greedy but after trying out:

```
grep -c -Po "$2" $1
```

It does not seem to make the grep expression non greedy??

Edit: People said Im not showing the patterns I working with so to clarify the patterns will be a RE so for example if the user inputs in

```
./thisfile.sh h file1.txt
```

It will find the number of times h appears in file1.txt
If the user inputs in

```
./thisfile.sh io file1.txt
```

It will find the number of times io appears in file1.txt.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You never show the pattern(s) that you're trying with. Also, `-E` and `-P` enables extended regular expressions (ERE) and Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), respectively.  You cannot get both. This is what the error ("conflicting matchers specified") tells you. What do you want, PCRE or ERE?  Also note that while `-o` gives you one line per match, the `-c` option will cancel the effect of `-o` and only return the number of lines matched. It is unclear what your intention is with this.  You also fail to quote `$1` and your command fails if the pattern in `$2` start with a dash.

Comment: I want extended regular expressions but I was told -P makes it non greedy by Stackoverflow??

Comment: `-P` does not make your regular expressions non-greedy automatically. The `-P` option enables Perl-compatible regular expressions (these are _different_ from extended regular expressions enabled with `-E`).  These can be greedy or non-greedy, depending on how you write them.  Ordinary regular expressions (with or without `-E`) can probably be used too, but would have to be written to not match greedily across substrings that you don't actually want to match.

Comment: ... see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count how many times a substring occurs in a file:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

grep -F -o -e "$1" | wc -l
```

You would use this script like so:

```
$ ./script e <script
       2
$ ./script ' -' <script
       4
```

```
$ ./script hey <file1
       3
$ ./script he <file1
       4
```

```
$ df | ./script %
       7
```

Here I'm counting the number of `e` characters in the script itself, and then the number of times the substring consisting of a space and a dash occurs in the script. Then I count a couple of substrings in the file presented in the question. The last example counts the number of percent signs in the output of `df` on my system.

The input data is read though standard input and the script's only argument is the substring that we want to look for and count.

The script consists of a single `grep`+`wc` pipeline.  It uses the non-standard (but commonly implemented)  `-o` option to return a list of non-overlapping matches on separate lines.
These lines are then counted with `wc -l`.

The call to `grep` uses `-F` to make the pattern be interperted as a string and not as a regular expression.  This makes it possible to count the number of times e.g. `*` occurs in a file, without having to escape the `*` (you would still have to *quote* the `*` to stop the shell from using it as a globbing pattern though).  Leave `-F` out if you want to use the pattern as a regular expression.

The `-e` option is used to tell `grep` that `$1` is the pattern.  If `-e` is not used, a pattern like `--version` would be interpreted as an option to `grep`.

Answer (score -1):

Some versions of `grep` (e.g. GNU's) allow you to give Perl compatible REs (check out [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org)), those are much more flexible than standard POSIX regexes.